# AS3: Check if there is an item selected in the List component?

Tags: actionscript-3

i've created a list component in flash with AS3,and i want to check if there is an item selected or not.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the `fl.controls.List` then `if(list.selectedIndex != -1)`